# Naan without tandoor?

Tags: bread, indian-cuisine, flatbread

I miss Indian food and especially good naan bread. I haven't really tried it, but I wanted to test if it's possible to make naan without a tandoor? Has anyone tried this, do you have some good tips and do you manage to make it just as good as the naan you get in India?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Never having been to India, I've only had naan from Indian restaurants and frozen from the supermarket. That said, I have made it with some success before.

The *best* method I've used is to grill (American) it. You can do it with a gas grill (barbecue) set to high, or with the hottest of hot charcoal. It doesn't quite approach the 900 F (480 C) typical of a tandoor, but it's close, especially with charcoal. Simply oil the grill and do 2-3 minutes per side.

The next best method I've tried is using a pizza stone in a blazing hot oven. The cook times are similar.

Comment: I second the pizza stone idea; it works a treat for me.

Comment: What about a pizza stone on the grill?

Comment: @chris: I've never tried it. However, I imagine that it would significantly restrict the airflow over the coals and thus result in a significantly lower temperature.

Comment: True.  It depends on the size of the grill.

Comment: In the US, at least, the typical pizza stone would occlude at least 80% of most grills.

Comment: Chris, you can't make classic pizza's in a domestic oven due to the limit on the sheer temperature the oven can reach. Due to this lower heat, the pizza base tends to come out 'biscuity' rather than crisp on the outside and chewy on the inside. It's a heat thing, domestic ovens just don't get hot enough.

Comment: Here is a link to Kenji Alt's article on making naan at home with a grill:  http://www.seriouseats.com/2011/08/the-food-lab-how-to-sort-of-make-naan-at-home.html?ref=obinsite

Answer (score 8):

If it's something you want to eat often, you could [make your own tandoor](http://www.poptastic.com/tandoor.html), or use a large [terracotta pot over your charcoal grill](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yFj5n_zhP-M&feature=related).

Comment: If you do decide to build a tandoor like crazy Alton Brown, _do not_ forget those gloves. Reaching over a 900 degree jet engine is not comfortable at all.

Comment: @hobodave - And burning arm hair really stinks.

Answer (score 5):

Although it doesn't simulate a tandoor, I stopped my quest for making the best naan after seeing the result from a Dutch oven on max heat. Fantastic. Lid on keeps the moisture in and stops it from going too crispy or hard, it bubbles up and parts of it get that slight charring.

Use a cheap Dutch oven as the charring marked my expensive one.

Try it, you'll be surprised!

I assume you're making the dough. I had a friend who tried it and said it wasn't that great. Then they were simply reheating those cardboard pre-packaged things.

Comment: Note that in some English speaking countries such as the UK/Aus/NZ, a "Dutch oven" is called a "casserole".

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can make perfectly acceptable naan breads without the need for a tandoori oven.

The keys are very high heat, ie under a domestic grill (watch while they puff up and brown) and yoghurt. You can also make them with baking powder without the need for yeast, which produces surprisingly good results.

Answer (score 1):

I've made naan on a (propane, american) grill with no problems, straight on the grate.  (maybe singed a little bit, that's what you want for naan).  Well, no problem grilling; I rolled them all out while I was still inside, and had them stacked up with dry waxed paper between them, and the weight of the stack meant that by the time I got maybe 5-6 of 'em done, the whole stack had glued itself together, which slowed me down quite a bit.

I've also done it stovetop in a cast iron pan to get a good sear, and then transfered to the oven to finish cooking while I made up the rest.  As I was rolling 'em as I went, I didn't have that sticking problem.

Comment: I do pita bread on the grill, and I also use wax paper to carry the bread outside. It helps a lot if you lightly dust each layer of wax paper with flour before slapping the pita on, and the top of the pita before the next layer of wax paper.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried baking with a pizza stone and tiles in the oven, but I get the best results from frying the naan in a cast-iron pan that has been lightly greased with oil on medium-high heat.

I admit that this is very far from a tandoor, but surprisingly naan that was fried turned out way better in terms of texture, air-bubbles, and flavour.

Admittedly I have never grilled it because I only cook one or two loaves at a time (keeping the dough in the fridge until it runs out), so I can't really justify firing up a charcoal grill.

Answer (score 1):

I miss my naan and gave up cooking it at home when I found I couldn't replicate it.

However, I did find roti-chapatis that you can cook in seconds on a skillet and come out very tasty and fresh, despite keeping forever in the fridge.

It's still indian bread, very tasty, and not totally disimilar. I filled my need when cooking curry at home.

Answer (score 1):

We can make naan at home on tawa and get the same look and taste too.

INGREDIENTS:
Wheat flour (Maida), 1 TSP curd, water, pinch of salt, 1 TSP ghee or butter 
STEPS:
1. Mix all the ingredients and make a soft dough 
2. Cover it with a muslin cloth and rest for 2 hours
3. Take a piece of dough, make it round 
4. Roll it like a chapati and grease some butter or ghee and make a triangle
5. Now roll the triangle chapati
6. grease water on one side of naan
7. let the tawa or flat pan become a bit hot
8. place the watered side of naan on the tawa
9. let it be for 30 seconds
10. with help of tongs reverse the side of tawa/flat pan on the flame and try to provide flame to all sides of the naan and it will come out automatically.
11. The watered naan will have the same crust which a tandoor provides.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is :- once you have your rolled out naans, wet one side with water then place the watered side6on a hot cast iro or similar tawra. Wait till you see bubbles appearing then flip the pan over, the naan will stay stuck to the pan, then put the inverted pan including tge bread over the flame. Wait till you get tge desired blistering and it's done. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you have a chapati pan and a gas grill then you can have a good go.  I think the secret to naan is that both sides have to cook at the same time, so if you get the pan very hot and then put your naan under a preheated grill, that's probably the closest you'll get without a tandoor.